# assign the constant value to the each respective index postion in the 2D matrix

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

I am obtaining undesired results in python.

Goal: I want to assign the constant value to the respective element of the 2D matrix.
I have indey list of the row and colum

```
idx_container_phi = [22, 19, 25, 23, 22, 21, 22, 30, 16, 12, 14] # row index
idx_container_theta = [22, 19, 10, 23, 22, 7, 22, 8, 16, 19, 11] # column index
thickness = 0.85
sphere_pixels  = 36
```

What I have done:
(1) First I have initialized the 2D matrix with certain shape.

```
matrix_thickness = np.array([ [0]*sphere_pixels for i in range(sphere_pixels)])
```

(2) I initialized for loop which excexutes till the range of the index list and assign the constant value.

```
for j in range(len(idx_container_phi)):
    matrix_thickness[idx_container_phi[j]-1][idx_container_theta[j]-1] = matrix_thickness[idx_container_phi[j]-1][idx_container_theta[j]-1] + thickness
```

However, while running the code, I got the matrix with null values in every element. How can I assign the constant value to the each respective index postion in the 2D matrix?

Desire Output: Matrix of the size 36 X 36. I want to assign the value of thickness (0.85) to the index position `[22, 22], [19, 19], [25, 10], [23, 23], [22, 22], [21, 7], [22, 22], [30, 8], [16, 16], [12, 19], [14, 11]`.

If any index comes two times, for ex. `[22, 22], [22, 22]`, then in this case, value of the `thickness (0.85)` should be added (0.85 + 0.85 = 1.70).

Comment: could you please a desired output to your question?

Comment: This question is a normalized and simplified version of the task what I am doing for my thesis. Therefore to answer your question, I would explain that I want to get the 2D matrix at the end which does have some value (mentioned in the question) at the matrix postion [22] [22], [19, 19], [25, 10], [23, 23] and so on.

Comment: I would suggest you to try this code in your system to get more idea behind the question.

Comment: yes, that's all right what you are saying. But if you post the desired output of your table to the given example it is much easier to understand your task and help.

Comment: The output of the code is a matrix of a size 36 X 36. It would be very mess if I write the result 36 X 36 matrix

Comment: then you'd have to scale ur example to a smaller size. you could do row and col index in a range of 10 and show your task on a 10x10 matrix. Please take a minute and read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to provide a MRE to get the best and fastest help. I think I understand now what you are trying to achieve, but it wasn't obvious from just reading your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should result in the array you are searching for:

```
idx_container_phi = [1, 7, 3, 4, 1] # row index
idx_container_theta = [3, 5, 2, 4, 3] # column index
thickness = 0.85
sphere_pixels  = 10

matrix_thickness = np.zeros(shape=(sphere_pixels, sphere_pixels))

for row, col in zip(idx_container_phi, idx_container_theta):
    matrix_thickness[row, col] += thickness
print(matrix_thickness)
```

Output:

```
[[0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   1.7  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.85 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.85 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.85 0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]]
```

Comment: Ahhan..that is what I was expecting. Cool. Thank you for your constant responses.

Comment: glad to help! Good luck with your thesis.

Comment: Vielen Dank bei Ihnen!!

Answer (score 0):

So there is also another way to do this. I got to know that by default numpy array bydefault initializes with `dtype = int`. Therefore even after assigning the constant value (which is float value) it changes to the interger value.

Mentioning `dtype=float` works and gives desired output.

```
matrix_thickness = np.array([ [0]*sphere_pixels for i in range(sphere_pixels)], dtype=float)
```